# ¿Por qué decimos "serpiente" y no "sierpe", si ambas vienen del latín "serpens"? ¿Cómo se convirtió "sierpe" en un caso particular de "serpiente"?

Tags: etimología, animales, latín

Mirando en el DLE vemos:

> [**sierpe**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Xq3Yh9k)
>   `Del lat. serpens 'serpiente'.`
>
> 1. f. Culebra de gran tamaño.

Y luego la más conocida:

> [**serpiente**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XgaWG9j)
>   `Del lat. serpens, -entis, de serpĕre 'serpentear'.`
>
> 1. f. Reptil ofidio sin pies, de cuerpo aproximadamente cilíndrico y muy largo respecto de su grueso, cabeza aplanada, boca grande y piel pintada simétricamente con colores diversos, escamosa, y cuya parte externa o epidermis muda por completo el animal de tiempo en tiempo.

Ambas con más acepciones que no vienen el caso. Las dos palabras tienen el mismo origen: el latín *serpens*, que [significa serpiente](https://www.etymonline.com/word/serpent#etymonline_v_23273).

¿Qué proceso llevó a *recluir* la palabra *sierpe* en un caso muy específico de serpiente, mientras que la palabra *serpiente*, más lejana etimológicamente, recibió todo el significado?

Comment: De hecho, la famosa calle Sierpes de Sevilla tiene una placa donde dice que también se la conoce como "calle de la sierpe" o "de la serpiente".

Comment: Una pregunta: ¿por qué dices que "serpiente" está más lejana etimológicamente? Simplemente "sierpe" viene de "serpens" cambiando la primera "e" por "ie" como suele ser habitual, mientras que "serpiente" viene de "serpentis", aplicando el mismo cambio pero en la segunda "e".

Comment: @Leonardo tienes razón. Lo edité. Siéntete libre de editar (o sugerir edición) si lo ves mejorable.

Comment: @Charlie a mi parecer, la distancia serpens → sierpe es menor que la de serpens → serpentis → serpiente, más aún cuando el DLE habla de _serpĕre_ (verbo _serpentear_). Es decir, parece como que _serpiente_ llegara a través de un nombre convertido en verbo y luego convertido en nombre otra vez. Pero vaya, lo mismo estoy interpretando erróneamente la etimología.

Comment: @fedorqui la palabra latina era "serpens, serpentis", se usaba una forma u otra según la declinación. No todas las palabras nos llegan de la misma declinación original. Yo interpreto que la distancia serpens → sierpe es la misma que serpentis → serpiente. Simplemente cada palabra procede de una forma diferente de la misma palabra original. Lo de que "serpes, serpentis" venga de "serpere" es igual en los dos casos, solo te está diciendo de dónde viene el sustantivo en latín, no deberías tenerlo en cuenta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Serpēns* (con *ē* larga) y *serpentis* son dos formas (caso nominativo y caso genitivo respectivamente) de la misma palabra latina, que es un sustantivo derivado del participio presente activo del verbo *serpĕre*.

En latín los casos estaban marcados por sufijos que el cambio fonético fue erosionando, de manera que primero se perdió la distinción entre el nominativo y los casos oblicuos (todos los otros), y luego también ésta. Con muchas palabras latinas esto implicaría llegar a formas idénticas en todos los casos, puesto que al quitarles los sufijos y perderse la distinción entre vocales cortas y largas, la forma de la raíz que queda termina siendo la misma en nominativo, acusativo, etc.

No es el caso de *serpēns*, cuyo paradigma tiene una sola forma de dos sílabas con acento tónico en la primera (precisamente el nom. sing. *serpēns*) y el resto con formas trisilábicas con acento en la segunda (*serpentem, serpentis*, etc.).

Por otro lado, en castellano, como en la mayoría de las otras lenguas romances, **los sustantivos no derivan del caso nominativo del latín, sino del acusativo** (o del caso oblicuo producto de la fusión del acusativo con los otros exceptuando el nominativo, que se cree que existió en romance, aunque no está documentado). Esto tiene cierto sentido por lo siguiente: la mayor parte de los sustantivos de uso común designan objetos, plantas, animales, etc. que en el habla habitual tienen más chances de aparecer como objetos directos o indirectos verbales, o como objetos de preposiciones, que como sujetos.

Como dije más arriba, sin embargo, en general no habría diferencia al final si se tomase un caso u otro. Pero en la tercera declinación el nominativo singular tiende a ser "rebelde"; es más corto y se acentúa diferente. Estas formas anómalas, incluso no mediando lo dicho anteriormente sobre los casos más frecuentes, son sustituidas por analogía con el resto del paradigma.

*Serpēns* es justamente de la tercera declinación.

Y aquí ya entra una hipótesis propia mía, porque no sé cuándo comenzó a usarse más *serpiente* que *sierpe*, pero se me ocurre que fueron adquiridas por el romance o el castellano antiguo en momentos diferentes. Ninguna de las dos es fonéticamente anómala, como ocurriría con un cultismo (*sierpe* muestra la diptongación y la erosión de las consonantes finales que se espera de cualquier palabra latina que haya pasado por los procesos regulares), pero *sierpe* es anómala por descender de un nominativo latino. Evidentemente, para cuando fueron aceptadas por el idioma, no fueron tomadas como formas de un mismo paradigma, y sus significados debieron diferenciarse. La palabra más común y regular, *serpiente*, quedó como la más general, y *sierpe* se especializó. Por qué, cuándo y cómo ocurrió esto, no lo sé.

Comment: Lo divertido del caso es que del primer párrafo extraemos que primero fue _serpentear_ y luego _serpiente_, siempre pensé que era al contrario.

Comment: @fedorqui La verdad que sí es curioso. No sé mucho de latín pero por lo que veo en diccionarios existían varios sinónimos, como *anguis* y *coluber* (de donde "anguila" y "culebra"). Con un animal tan propenso a tabúes no sería raro que hubiese palabras alternativas.

Comment: In the second para you seem to suggest that the nominative fused with the others but in the fourth para you seem to suggest that it was all the others except the nominative which fused together first. Or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: @mdewey No, actually it's rather badly worded. I'll correct now.